# Special IDs in Python , want to create a Help section in Menu

Tags: python, wxpython

I am building a small app using wxPython.I have created a menu bar , added items in that . Now
i have created menu option "Help" and "About" . 
For about , i found a special id ID_ABOUT which is great . For About , you can create an object of type example->

```
   "info = wx.AboutDialogInfo()"
```

You can then add a number of things like

```
    info.SetIcon(wx.Icon('icons/hunter.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG))
    info.SetName('My App')
    info.SetVersion('1.0.1')
    info.SetDescription(description)
    info.SetCopyright('(C) 2012 xxxxx')
    info.SetWebSite('www.XYZ.com')
    info.SetLicence(licence)
    info.AddDeveloper('Mr.ABC')
    wx.AboutBox(info)
```

Now , i found a lot more ids like ID_HELP , ID_HELP_CONTEXT .
I want to create a HELP Section in my menu . So how do i use these IDs . Is there any special ID for creating a HELP Menu ...I found all these IDs but these is no detail information over the internet as to how to use these ids . So if any body has any idea , please do share . Thank you guys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you have some misunderstanding about the meaning and use of [`wx.ID_XXX` constants](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_stdevtid.html) (Stock IDs).

These constants correspond to a series of integer identifiers (most of the in the range from 4999 to 5999) that wxPython reserves for special purposes for widget creation (such as for giving an special icon to a dialog o menu item and for assuring cross-platform correct behavior of widgets.)

You can get available IDs with:

```
import wx

x = dir(wx)
for y in x:
    if y.startswith('ID_'):
        print y
```

There is one of these identifiers `wx.ID_ANY` (with value -1) that is often used when we want wxpython to automatically assing an ID number to a widget. For example in:

```
frame = wx.Frame(parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, title="", .....)
```

Comment: I used the id ID_ABOUT like this - >

    'item3_2=teesra.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"A&bout\tAlt-B","About Section")'

     'self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout,item3_2)'

So i wanted to use 

     'item3_1=teesra.Append(wx.ID_HELP_CONTENTS,"&Help\tAlt-H","Help Section")' 
     'self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnHelp,item3_1)'

So now, what do i create in my self.OnHelp , a simple message box? . I wanted to know about the usage of this ID_HELP_CONTENTS , or if any other is available....